# Creating a alert functionality in django wagtail

Tags: html, django, alert, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am trying to create a alert section for a menu (similar to the menu on this page https://metageeky.github.io/mega-menu/responsive-header.html)

*Each alert should have an effective date (date alert is “posted” live) and resolved date (date alert is “removed” live). Each alert will also have a maximum of one to two sentences of text describing situation.
The number of active/current alerts will appear in parenthesis following the icon and ALERT link text.

The icon and text are Dark Orange. When you hover over the icon and text, an underline appears.

When users click on the link, they are taken to a page that lists all active alerts. At bottom of page, message displays “If you are experiencing an issue, please contact us at....”

**If there are no Alerts:**

The number of alerts in parenthesis following the icon and link text will not appear.

Both the icon and alert text will be Primary Blue.

When Users click on the link, they are taken to a secondary alerts page that displays a message that says “There are currently no active alerts. If you are experiencing an issue, please contact us at...”

How would i achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It might be more helpful if you can update your question with the following; 1.are the alerts meant to show in the Wagtail admin area or on the front facing website? 2. What is the Django model you have made (or would think you may make) for this? 3. Are alerts meant to show globally (every page) or just some subset of pages? 4. Who needs access to edit/create alerts?

Comment: Hi, the alerts are meant to be shown on the main page, user can edit it in the wagtail admin area, I think this will be via wagtail, and it can show on some subset of pages. Anyone that is admi ncan access edit or create alerts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to unpack in your question but here is a high level approach.

## 1. Define your model

- Read the [Django docs on how to create a `Model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/)
- Read the [Django docs on what types of `Field`s exist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#field-types)
- In your `models.py`, you will need to create a new model that has all the data you need for your requirements.

```py
from django.db import models


class Alert(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
    date_from = models.DateTimeField()
    date_to = models.DateTimeField()
```

## 2. Ensure you can edit/manage your model data

- Now you need to provide a way for your admin users to access the data model, edit & create items.
- Wagtail has a great [Snippets](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/snippets.html) feature that allows this to work without too many changes, you will need to add `@register_snippet` on your model and also define some `panels`.

```py
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

from django.db import models


@register_snippet
class Alert(models.Model):
    #... fields (defined above)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('description'),
        FieldPanel('date_from'),
        FieldPanel('date_to'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## 3. Prepare a template tag to show the queried data

- Now you will need to work out how to query the model in a way that it will return the alerts based on your requirements (current date should be within the date range of the data).
- Django has docs on [writing queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/)
- The simplest way to get the results of this query into the template will be with a custom [Template Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)
- An `inclusion_tag` is a way to have a small template fragment that can be used anywhere with custom data (without having to pass it into each View).
- In the example below, you will still need to create the template file `current_alerts.html` which will contain how you want to render the alerts.
- In your template tag template you can also use the [`page_url`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/writing_templates.html#pageurl-tag) tag to provide a link to the `alerts_page`

```py
# template_tags/custom_tags.py
# remember to create a template_tags/__init__.py file also
from django import template

from .models import Alert


register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('current_alerts.html')
def show_alerts():
    # just returns all alerts, but this query can be refined to suit what you need
    current_alerts = alerts.Objects.all()
    alerts_page = AlertPage.Objects.all().first() # this assumes there will only ever be one
    return {'alerts_page',alerts_page,'current_alerts': current_alerts}
```

## 4. Use your template tag & add styling

- Now you need to include the tag at the top of the page inside your root/shared template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load custom_tags %}


{% block body_class %}template-blogpage{% endblock %}

​{% show_alerts %}

{% block content %}...{% endblock %}
```

## 5. Create a `AlertsPage`

- You will need to create a new `Page` type to redirect users to within your alerts link.
- https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html
- This `Page` can be anywhere in your tree and the `Page`'s view template can also use the same shared template or you can pass the alerts to the view via the [template context](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#template-context)

Comment: I followed this steps, but no luck. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Hey @soupi - it would be good to get a bit more detail, which part is not working for you and how? Are you getting an error somewhere? Have you run the db migrations? Have you tried restarting the Dev server after making changes, have you added some Print logging to see what is breaking in the view?